# Missing Image on Unsubscribe Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I am not sure if this is an artifact of the new design or something that has been around, but I just loaded a page with an image that didn't load:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good call, we'll fix that; this is a standard image across the network.

[image]